# How to hot deploy scala+Java EE 6?

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, java-ee-6, hotdeploy

I am building a development environment for a Java EE 6 application that i would like to build with scala and run with JBoss AS 7.

I was able to get everything running with maven, but not a IDE that can hot-deploy my changes, as i would be able to do in Java.

Eclipse was my first choice, but i was not able to make the scala plugin work with WTP.

Could anyone suggest a IDE / build tool for Scala + Java EE 6 that works well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly hot deployment, but [JRebel](http://sales.zeroturnaround.com/) is free for Scala developers. You don't have to redeploy then.

Comment: FWIW, eclipse+jrebel is what i ended up with·